# library() function fails to load multiple packages

Tags: r

When I included janitor package with other packages, it did not load.

> library(MASS, caret, stepPlr, janitor)

Error in library(MASS, caret, stepPlr, janitor) : object 'janitor' not found

When I ran that command separately with only janitor package, it got loaded into session; with no error

```
> library(janitor)
Warning message:
package ‘janitor’ was built under R version 3.3.3
```

Is there any limit with including x number of packages at a time? Or there is something wrong with my RStudio?

Comment: If you read the help page for `library` it mentions *one* package at a time only. It uses the singular, `the name of a package, given as a name or literal character string, or a character string`, not the plural.

Comment: You can create a function which does this using something like `library_all = function(...) sapply(list(...), library)`. Add this to your `.Rprofile` and it is available for all your scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `library()` function isn't meant to load multiple libraries, a better approach is to create a list of packages, and use `require()` to check if they are installed and if not install them. See example below:

```
requiredPackages <- c("MASS", "caret", "stepPlr", "janitor")


ipak <- function(pkg){
        new.pkg <- pkg[!(pkg %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
        if (length(new.pkg))
                install.packages(new.pkg, dependencies = TRUE)
        sapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE)
}

ipak(requiredPackages)
```

Comment: Thanks. That Works. :)

Comment: @Wwalk Happy to help. Have a great day.

Answer (score 5):

The function `p_load` from the `pacman` package allows for listing multiple packages like this, and will install them if any are not already present:

```
library(pacman)
p_load(MASS, caret, stepPlr, janitor)
```

This is not only user-friendly, it also improves reproducibility for running the same script across multiple users or environments.

Answer (score 2):

The straight answer was indicated by @Technophobe01

```
sapply(c('MASS', 'caret', 'stepPlr', 'janitor'), require, character.only = TRUE)
```